# SQL query - split out count() results into one line of GROUP BY results

Tags: mysql, sql

I want to use GROUP BY to get a row per month-year. Additionally, I have another field which, for this example, is colour and can have values of Blue or Red.

I want to see a table with columns for Blue, Red, month and year = I want to count the number of each colour per month-year. Can I do this with an SQL query?

I know that count(colour) will give me the total number of rows for each month-year.

It's good if it's possible to do this but some solutions may involve coding in "Red" and "Blue" = just 2 values. Is it possible to run a query to execute a count which will split out the "answers" from the count into each line rather than a line each?

Example data:

| Year | Month | Day | Colour |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2021 | 3 | 6 | Blue |
| 2021 | 3 | 7 | Blue |
| 2021 | 3 | 8 | Blue |
| 2021 | 3 | 9 | Red |
| 2021 | 4 | 5 | Blue |
| 2021 | 4 | 6 | Red |
| 2021 | 4 | 7 | Blue |
| 2021 | 4 | 8 | Red |
| 2021 | 4 | 9 | Red |

to give result

| Year | Month | Blue | Red |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2021 | 3 | 3 | 1 |
| 2021 | 4 | 2 | 3 |

I'm doing this in mysql and also in javascript using alasql but a suggestion for any version of SQL will probably be helpful here...

Comment: Look at pivot...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `SUM(CASE WHEN...` to do this

```
SELECT Year, Month, SUM(CASE WHEN Colour = 'Blue' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS Blue, etc
FROM table
GROUP BY Year, Month
```

Comment: This assumes the colors are known in advance.  a dynamic pivot would support X colors; but uses dynamic SQL... so... not as much fun...  Perhaps it would be best to just count the lines group by color as well and let the UI do the pivot...  (not a complaint of the solution, just a comment depending on the data involved)  presentation is usually done in teh UI and should be avoided in the database;  IMO.

Comment: Thanks to all - SUM will do it.

In effect, I asked for a flexible method of getting all the possible SUMs onto the one line. If I know what the possible values are, and I do know or can know, then I can generate a query to do the work, generating a SUM term for each in turn. Excellent!

Answer (score 1):

I will suggest fixing the design. You could store date in one column only, in date format. Be aware of the [MySQL reserved word](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/keywords.html) such as `YEAR`, `MONTH`,`DATE`, you should use backticks for those columns.

If you only have blue and red color you could do an easy solution:

```
SELECT Year, 
       Month, 
       SUM(Colour='Blue') as Blue, 
       SUM(Colour='Red') as Red   
FROM test_tbl    
GROUP BY `Year`, `Month`;
```

> Result:
>
> ```
> Year  Month   Blue    Red
> 2021    3      3       1
> 2021    4      2       3
> ```

[Demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=7e46dd1a5cf79dffd7f5150c8dd9e486)

Answer (score 0):

You could do the following:

```
  GROUP BY Year(yourdate),
     Month(yourdate),
     Day(yourdate),
     Colour
```

Group By is not limited to acting on a single column (or expression).

Answer (score 0):

You can write a query like this

```
SELECT Year, 
       Month, 
       COUNT(CASE WHEN Colour = 'Blue' THEN 1 END) AS Blue, 
       COUNT(CASE WHEN Colour = 'Red' THEN 1 END) AS Red    
FROM table    
GROUP BY Year, Month;
```

Comment: COUNT counts all non-null values, including 0. (Tip: SUM instead.)

Comment: or leave off the ELSE 0 to produce nulls

Comment: Thanks @jarlh,@ysth